Generalizing Bernoulli to Binomial without summing
A Binomial random variable is a generalization of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables by summing them, arrived at by performing discrete convolution on their distributions.
A Multinomial random variable is likewise a generalization of i.i.d. Categorical random variables, however it is not obtained by summing them. Is there a term for the operation that maps Categoricals to the Multinomial, and what is its relationship to convolution?
(more precise technical description what it's worth)
Consider a joint distribution over $n$ i.i.d. Categorical random variables, each with $k$ categories (e.g. rolling a die multiple times). Each outcome lives in $\mathbb{N}^n$. We can consider a mapping from the outcomes in $\mathbb{N}^n$ to the support of a corresponding Multinomial distribution defined over $\mathbb{N}^{k-1}$ (it is not $\mathbb{N}^{k}$ because the marginal for $X_i$ is a constant given the other $\{X_j|j \neq i\}$, thus there are only $k-1$ degrees of freedom). This operation must have convolution as a special case when $k=2$. What is this operation?

Your joint distribution of i.i.d. categorical random variables $(C_1,\ldots,C_n)$ really takes values in $S^n$ where $S$ is the set of categories. Enumerate $S = \{ s_1,\ldots,s_k \}$, then for $1\le i \le k$ set $$X_i = \sum_{j=1}^n 1_{\{s_i\}}(C_j)$$ i.e. the number of $C$'s that equal $s_i$. Then $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_k)$ is the multinomial random variable you seek.

An indicator function $1_{\cdot}[]$ when applied to any discrete random variable (categorical in this case) produces a Bernoulli. Since you are summing, it seems we are essentially still doing convolution applied to a bunch of Bernoulli RVs, but this time we have many separate summations producing separate $X_i$s to compose the multinomial.

What is the term for the distribution produced from simply summing i.i.d. Categoricals? The domain of this distribution is just a scalar.

I don't think that's the right thing to consider as the "sum of of two categories" may not be defined, or may not be a meaningful quantity.

In general yes, the Multinomial treats different categories as incommensurable. But it can still practical in many situations; consider for example the sum of multiple dice rolls. I'd be surprised if this doesn't have a name. The vector of RVs composing the Multinomial could be dot-product'd with the vector [1,2,3,4,5,6] to arrive at the summed RV I am talking about - this should be the same as simply summing $n$ i.i.d. Categorical RVs.
